# Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: ) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, apache, php-7, php-7.1

I have a local PHP7 & Apache environment on my Mac. All my scripts from one site are showing this error at the end of the page:

> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data using user defined save
>   handler. (session.save_path: ) in Unknown on line 0

The error-log doesn't show more detail on the cause:

```
[Tue Oct 10 22:37:44.981703 2017] [php7:warn] [pid 17853] [client ::1:62267] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: ) in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked my php.ini, since that "session.save_path" seems to be a reference to it, and there this parameter has the default value:

```
;session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

It's the lack of detail in this error that throws me off. How can I get closer to the cause of this? Trying to pin down where this is coming from.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71070 your session handler is not accessing /tmp most likely due to permissions...

Comment: Interesting. `/tmp/` permissions are set to `drwxrwxrwt`, is that wrong?

Comment: Did you fix this with the new filerights ,.... plesae share the solution

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and realized that the replace query had quotes in its table name. The error was fixed after removing the single quotes.

Incorrect

```
replace into 'sessions' values('value1','value2','value3')
```

Correct

```
replace into sessions values('value1','value2','value3')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just stop your Mysql Server and Apache Server. Than Restart your Apache Server First and then Restart your Mysql Server.